# Selenium: Iterate through child elements with different class names

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I want to iterate through child elements of parent . Access the child element, extract price information and move on to next child element.

Here is my code

```
pack_size_elements =  wd.find_elements(By.XPATH , "//div[@class='_1LiCn']/div")
for element in pack_size_elements:
    price = element.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class ='_2j_7u']").text.strip()
    print(price)
```

Output:

```
Rs 61
Rs 61
Rs 61
Rs 61
```

**Concern/What I want help with**: Price output should change in each iteration as element changes. But I am only getting same price as first element price

Desired Output:

```
Rs 61
Rs 299.50
Rs 1797
Rs 1830
```

HTML outer element

[image: HTML element]

1st Child element

[image: Ist child element]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
for element in pack_size_elements:
    price = element.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class ='_2j_7u']").text.strip()
    print(price)
```

By adding a dot before the `//`, you are searching within that element only.